# One POST index shows up true, another undefined, yet both have been implemented (what seems to be) the same way

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have this problem I've been working on and can't seem to figure out. At the end of the day I would like to pass some values to a php script from a user form. I am working with files that were written a long time ago and have tried to treat the variable I am trying to pass the same way the original author tried to treat his own. Yet, despite trying to keep the approach the same, I am getting different results. Specifically, in the php script where I want to pass these variables, when I echo the value of $_POST['whole'] I get true or false, yet when I echo the value of $_POST['plotX'] I get a variable undefined error.

I apologize for the large amount of code, but I hope that if you search for terms queryDataCenterOfMass and plotX you will see what I am referring to.

The HTML portion comes out as follows. This is where the user selects true or false for 'whole' and true or false for 'plotX'. This is actually code from the webpage, php is used to generate this code, but I thought it would be simpler to paste the HTML.

```
<div id="wholeDiv" class="dynamicDiv">
                                    <b>Whole</b>
                                    <br>
                                    <select id="whole" name="whole" class="atomTypeSelect">
                                        <option value="">&gt;&gt;Select&lt;&lt;</option>
                                        <option value="true">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="false" selected="">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

<div id="plotXDiv" class="dynamicDiv">
                                    <b>Plot x dimension</b>
                                    <br>
                                    <select id="plotX" name="plotX" class="atomTypeSelect">
                                        <option value="">&gt;&gt;Select&lt;&lt;</option>
                                        <option value="true">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="false" selected="">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

The next part is the code that creates the submit button. The important part is, I belive, the onclick portion, which calls the function queryDataCenterofMass, which is given in a separate javascript file and I pasted below this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="table" value= <?php echo $_GET['schema'] ?>/> 
<input type="hidden" name="queryName" 
                                                                                                    value= <?php echo $result[0]['query_id'] ?>/>
                    <input type='Submit' value=' Query Data' name='funcSearch'
                           onclick="queryDataCenterofMass(('<?php echo $result[0]['query_id'] ?>'),('<?php echo $_GET['schema'] ?>'),($('#firstFrame').val()) ,($('#lastFrame').val()) ,($('#skip').val()) , ($('#minX').val()) ,  ($('#minY').val()) ,
                               ($('#minZ').val()), ($('#maxX').val()), ($('#maxY').val()),  ($('#maxZ').val()), ($('#whole').val()), ($('#whole_pcb').val()), ($('#molName').val()),($('#atomTypeDll').val()), ($('#atomID').val()), ($('#molID').val()) ), ($('#plotX').val()), ($('#plotY').val()), ($('#plotZ').val()); false;"
                           class='dynamicParamButton'><br/><br/>
```

Here is the definition of queryDataCenterofMass. It seems to use a jQuery function to pass everything via post to comfunction.php.

```
function queryDataCenterofMass(queryId, schema, firstFrame, lastFrame, frameSkip, minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ, whole, wholePcb, molName, atomType, atomID, molID, plotX, plotY, plotZ) {

$("#waiting").show(500);
$("#interface").hide(0);

// generate a random number to pass to function.php and append to the end of our gnuplot files to make them unique
var random_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);

$.post('./function_files/comfunction.php',
    {
        random_num: random_num,
        query_id: queryId,
        simschema: schema,
        firstFrame: firstFrame,
        lastFrame: lastFrame,
        frameSkip: frameSkip,
        minX: minX,
        minY: minY,
        minZ: minZ,
        maxX: maxX,
        maxY: maxY,
        maxZ: maxZ,
        whole: whole,
        whole_pcb: wholePcb,
        molName: molName,
        atomType: atomType,
        atomID: atomID,
        molID: molID,
        plotX: plotX,
        plotY: plotY,
        plotZ: plotZ
    },

    function (data) {
        $("#waiting").hide(0);
        $("#results").show(500);
        var img = document.getElementById("com_img");
        img.src = "../queries/gnuplot_tmp_files/gnuplot_output" + random_num;

        $('div#message').html(data).fadeIn({duration: 700});

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('div#message').offset().top
        });
    });
```

}

So that's it. I am not sure why in comfunction.php the variable $_POST['plotX'] is undefined yet other variables, including $_POST['whole'] are not. Solving this problem is very important to me... if there is some way I can better ask this question, or more information I can provide, please don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick line

```
 ($('#molID').val()) ),
```

Seems to have an extra bracket here. Which makes the onclick callback end early, before the plotX and other elements could be sent.

Protip/s:
- Bad idea to load mix such javascript eventhandlers inside HTML
- I simply loaded the html in a IDE which showed the syntax error (among others)
- use browser developer tools.